# How to decode a JSON dictionary without using its key with Codable protocol

Tags: json, swift, api, codable

Let's say I have this response from a Weather API.

```
{  
   "2019-08-27 19:00:00":{  
      "temperature":{  
         "ground":292,
      },
      "pressure":{  
         "see_level":101660
      }
   },
   "2019-08-27 23:00:00":{  
      "temperature":{  
         "ground":292,
      },
      "pressure":{  
         "see_level":101660
      }
   }
}
```

I have Result data type which contains a temperature property that can contains any JSON dictionary in the ground object

```
struct Result: Codable {
    let ????: [String: Any]

}

struct Temperature: Codable {
    let ground: Int
}
```

Do anyone know how to achieve this with Codable protocol to correctly parse each forcast without using its key?

Answer (score 2):

Create structs for pressure, temperature and the enclosing object

```
struct Pressure: Decodable {
    let see_level: Int
}

struct Temperature: Decodable {
    let ground: Int
}

struct WeatherData: Decodable {
    let pressure : Pressure
    let temperature : Temperature
}
```

Then decode a dictionary

```
JSONDecoder().decode([String:WeatherData].self, from: ...)
```

The dictionary keys represent the dates

Comment: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: My bad, It's `see_level` and I read se**a** level. I updated the answer. By the way don't print `localizedDescription`, print always the `error` instance to get a more descriptive error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate models and serializers from JSON using this website https://app.quicktype.io

> WeatherValue

```
public struct WeatherValue: Codable {
   public let temperature: Temperature
   public let pressure: Pressure

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case temperature
       case pressure
   }

   public init(temperature: Temperature, pressure: Pressure) {
       self.temperature = temperature
       self.pressure = pressure
   }
}
```

> Pressure

```
public struct Pressure: Codable {
   public let seeLevel: Int

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case seeLevel = "see_level"
   }

   public init(seeLevel: Int) {
       self.seeLevel = seeLevel
   }
}
```

> Temperature

```
public struct Temperature: Codable {
   public let ground: Int

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case ground
   }

   public init(ground: Int) {
       self.ground = ground
   }
}
```

> Typealias

```
public typealias Weather = [String: WeatherValue]
```

> Decode

```
let weather = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Weather.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: so helpfull, thank's